# Reactive Extensions (Rx) for Silverlight - Where is System.Interactive.dll moved to?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, system.interactive

I've just installed the newest Release (v1.1.10425) of Rx for Silverlight 4 and 5 (Beta). I've seen that the package is missing 3 DLLs I've used in my projects in the past:

```
System.CoreEx.dll
System.Interactive.dll
System.Observable.dll
```

What I'm actually missing is the following extension method:

```
System.Linq.EnumerableEx.Run<TSource>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)
```

Where has it moved to? Was it merged with an other assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't exist in the latest release, sorry. You can still use the System.Interactive from a previous release though.

**Update:** This is [now a NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/Ix_Experimental-Main)

**Update 2:** There is now [a non experimental NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/Ix-Main), as well as [non experimental Ix-Async](http://nuget.org/packages/Ix-Async/)

Comment: Probably not - they might be released as a separate download

Comment: I had to revert back to the previous release of the nuget package because of this.

Comment: @PaulBetts Any chance this is going to be re-released soon? Its loss saddens me.

Comment: Any news on this? We cannot use Rx in Silverlight 4, becuase of this missing assembly

Comment: EnumerableEx isn't part of Rx at all. It's part of Ix, which is linked right above your comment.